# Moving dropdown container if it exceeds the window height

Tags: jquery, html, less

I made a dropdown that shows up when you click an element. It works fine mostly, with the single exception if the contents of the dropdown (`li` items) are too many and the container of the dropdown is near the bottom of the page, it causes the window to expand and you have to scroll down to see the rest of its items.

My solution to this was trying to make the position of the container show up above the container instead of below it, by detecting if heights exceed. So far I have been unsuccessful as it's always located above the container, even if it's not exceeding the window height.

HTML:

```
<div class="selector">
    <div class="title" data-action="open">Open</div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="itemList">
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on("click", ".selector > *[data-action='open']", function() {
        const selector = $(this).parent(".selector");
        selector.find(".title").toggleClass("selected");
        selector.find(".container").toggle();
        if($(window).height() > selector.find(".container").height()) {
            selector.find(".container").css("top", ("-" + selector.find(".container").height() - 20));
        }
    });
});
```

And my LESS if needed:

```
.selector {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    > .container {
        display: none;
        background: #FFF;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        right:0;
        width:100%;
        top: 50px;
        max-height:500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        .borderRadius();
        .boxShadow();

        > .itemList {
            margin: 0 -12px;
            padding: 12px;

            > li {
                padding: 12px 18px;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: @body-text-color-secondary;
                .transition(@background-transition-duration, @background-transition-style);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: you can just use javascript to check window height, the dropdown position and the dropdown height and move it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Condition you are using to check window hight and list height is wrong.

Try below one. This check available height is less than height required by list then it will display at top. Also checked that available height at above should be greater than height required by list, if not then it will increase page height, list will come below and show scroll bar as it was behaving previously.

I have modified code. you can add/remove `'<br/>'/'<li>Hello</li>'` to test for all kind of scenario.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).on("click", ".selector > *[data-action='open']", function() {
            const selector = $(this).parent(".selector");
            selector.find(".title").toggleClass("selected");
            selector.find(".container").toggle();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var titleOffsetTop = selector.find(".title").offset().top;
            var titleHeight = selector.find(".title").height();
            var containerHeight = selector.find(".container").height();
            debugger;
            if ( windowHeight < ( titleOffsetTop + titleHeight + containerHeight) &&  containerHeight < titleOffsetTop ){
                selector.find(".container").css("top", (-containerHeight-titleHeight) );
            } else {
           selector.find(".container").css("top", titleHeight);
          }
        });
    });
```

```css
.selector {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
    .selector  .container {
        display: none;
        background: #FFF;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        right:0;
        width:100%;
        top: 50px;
        max-height:500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
       }

    .selector  .container  .itemList {
            margin: 0 -12px;
            padding: 12px;
}
      .selector  .container  .itemList li {
                padding: 12px 18px;
                cursor: pointer;
                color: @body-text-color-secondary;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="selector">
    <div class="title" data-action="open">Open</div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="itemList">
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something seem to be off here. If I zoom out my browser and click the trigger, the item list appears to be at the very bottom of the window as well as expanding the window height A LOT (so I have to scroll down more than before). Otherwise it's still always shown at the top.

Comment: The `else` block is not needed, as it's located at the bottom by default. However as said, it's still only listed above the container (as was the issue in the beginning) - unless I actually zoom out the browser.

Comment: Else required when your page is adding content at bottom dynamically without page load. Also when your options list is increasing or descreasing dynamically. There could be more scenario for else condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does seem to work indeed but for me it is behaving really strange. If I zoom out to 80% or lower, it will behave as expected. However if the browser window size is above 80%, it's always at the top. Any idea why it's behaving like that?